# Json Api Resources | response with array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I am using the json api resource gem in my project.

I have setup a simple resource

```
module V1
  class ExpectedPaymentResource < JSONAPI::Resource
    attributes :registration_id, :invoiced_amount_due, :date_due, :status, :created_at, :updated_at
  end
end
```

In my controller I get an array of ExpectedPayments objects from a service

```
expected_payments = CreateExpectedPayments.new(registration_params).call
```

I now need to return the `expected_payments` in the json api format. So from what I understand, I should use the [serializer](http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.8/guide/serializer.html)

I do this

```
render json: JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(ExpectedPaymentResource).serialize_to_hash(ExpectedPaymentResource.new(expected_payments, nil))
```

And I get `<NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for <Array:0x005642734fa6f8>>`

And then I tried:

```
render json: JSONAPI::ResourceSerializer.new(ExpectedPaymentResource).serialize_to_hash(ExpectedPaymentResource.new(expected_payments[0], nil))
```

And that worked for the 1st object in the array.

The [documentation](http://jsonapi-resources.com/v0.8/guide/serializer.html) says "`ResourceSerializer` has a `serialize_to_hash` method that takes a resource instance or array of resource instances to serialize."

How do I get it to work with an array of resource instances? I can't see any examples in the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Rails. Please try active_model_serializer which brings convention over configuration to your JSON generation.

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Yon can stop wronging how you can generate a JSON response once you start using AMS.

Below is the getting start guide for AMS,

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md